# Shrink C: with GParted

Tags: windows, partitioning, gparted

I tried to shrink the C: partition on my PC to make space for a GNU/Linux System. My Drive is GPT formatted and has these partition on it:

```
DISKPART> lis par

Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Restore            450 MB  1024 KB
Partition 2    System              99 MB   451 MB
Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   550 MB
Partition 4    Primary            464 GB   566 MB
Partition 5    Restore            505 MB   465 GB
```

When I try to shrink the Primary Partition, Windows tells me that I cannot shrink C, because there is no free space left.

Is it save to shrink C: with GParted from a Live GNU/Linux System or will I break something?

Edit: Can I also move the last Restore partition or is it required at that place?

Answer (score 1):

Shrinking your C: (partition 4 by the looks of it) with GPartEd is in general perfectly safe to do.
However it is possible that Windows refuses to boot after that operation: Missing bootloader, missing partition errors.
If that is the case start your computer from a Windows install disk and let it repair the Windows installation. That usually fixes that problem in a few minutes and Window will work fine again.

As for the last Restore partition: Without far more details it is impossible to say. Could be safe, could be not. PC manufacturers use all sort of strange factory-restore methods and this may be related to that. Deleting or moving it is generally safe in that case, but may break the factory-restore functionality.
Leaving it be, but putting an extra partition on the disk (between 4 and 5) may also break it. (If the factory mechanism hardcoded assumes it always is partition 5.)
If the Restore partition has another use, I've got no idea what happens if you mess with it.

PS: From within the GPartEd mini-Linux distribution you could open that Restore partition to look what is in there. That might give you a clue what it is for.